# Forcing reload of a html page after a small wait

Tags: html, reload

I have a html page A and a link in the page which opens up page B in a new window. How to reload the page A on clicking and opening this link ?

**EDIT:**

I should have been more clear. Page B opens in a new window and not as a popup. The hyperlink in question has its target attribute set to _blank. Taking a clue from the answers that I got (Thanks guys !), I tried setting onclick = "window.location.reload()" and it works perfectly fine.

However I have a problem. In fact another question altogether. How to make sure that the reload of page A waits until the page opened in the new window (page B) loads ?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('pageB.htm');window.location.reload();">open page b</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to do

```
<a href="# " onClick="window.open('newPage.htm','window','width=400,height=200')">link</a>
```

If I remember correctly that should open the window and then since the return has not been suppresed will reload load the page.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you want based on your wording, but if you want to reload the opening window from a link in the popup try

```
self.opener.location.href = self.opener.location.href;
```

Edit, based on your new comments just use the code above in the body onload of the new window

```
<body onload="self.opener.location.href = self.opener.location.href;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_settimeout.asp) to delay the reload.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openPage(elem) {
    function reloadCurrentPage() {
        location.reload();
    }

    var page = window.open(elem.href, '_blank');
    page.onload = function() {
        reloadCurrentPage();
    }

    if (/MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // fix for IE
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (page.document.readyState == 'complete') {
                clearInterval(timer);
                reloadCurrentPage();
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
</script>

<p><a href="second.html" onclick="openPage(this); return false;">second.html</a></p>
```